# How to display in the main thread an integer incremented by the last started thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I wrote a little program which allows the user to find a file in a directory. The function is recursive and each crossed-directory is handled by a new thread. An integer, which counts the number of crossed directories, is incremented by each thread.

When the file is found, all these threads are `interrupted`, except the main-thread.

**I want to display this integer in my thread-main, when the file is found but I don't understand how I could do this. Should I use `join` in Launcher ?**

Here's the source. Thank you in advance !

FILE : LAUNCHER

```
public class Launcher {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            // Find's launch
            Find find = new Find("tests.txt", "C:/Users/xxx/google_drive");
            find.start();
            // HERE : SHOULD I USE JOIN() ????
            System.out.println("Number of crossed-directories " + Find.number_of_dirs);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

FILE : FIND

```
public class Find extends Thread {
    private static ArrayList<Find> all_threads = new ArrayList<Find>();
    private String file, dir;
    protected static int number_of_dirs;

    public Find(String file, String dir) {
        this.file = file;
        this.dir = dir;

        synchronized (Find.class) {
            Find.all_threads.add(this);
            Find.incrementNumberOfDirs();
        }
    }

    private static synchronized void incrementNumberOfDirs() {
        Find.number_of_dirs++;
    }

    public void run() {
        this.search(this.dir);
    }

    public void search(String file_path) {
        File file = new File(file_path);

        if(file.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Searching in the directory... " + file.getAbsolutePath());
            for(File found_file : file.listFiles()) {
                if(Find.interrupted()) {
                    synchronized (Find.class) {
                        Find.all_threads.remove(this);
                    }
                    return;
                }

                if(found_file.isDirectory()) {
                    Find find = new Find(this.file, found_file.getAbsolutePath());
                    find.start();
                } else {
                    if(this.file.equals(found_file.getName())) {
                        Find.all_threads.forEach(thread -> thread.interrupt());
                        System.out.println("File was found here : " + found_file.getAbsolutePath() + " !");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to clarify your question and show where you used synchronised in your sample code.

Comment: I have edited my post, thank you !